mariadb-backup consistently produces corrupt backups after 11.4 upgrade
We recently upgraded mariadb 10.3 to 11.4. Upgrade went surprisingly smoothly, but now backups taken using mariabackup are consistently corrupted.
We use mariabackup to create replicas using the following command:
# mariadb-backup --backup

This commands completes successfully without any errors.
We then prepare the backup using:
# mariadb-backup --prepare

This also completes without any errors.
Then we copy the data to the new replica using:
# mariadb-backup --copy-back

Zero errors here as well.
We correct the permissions and try to start the server, but it always dies with the following log message:
2024-11-24  9:26:26 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 11.4.3-MariaDB source revision 5ab81ffe0097a22a774957df28c5223cf0201de3 server_uid fsZ5HKLl3RQH0TdDFI+Hiy01Xnc= as process 12191
2024-11-24  9:26:26 0 [Note] mariadbd: AWS KMS plugin: loaded key 1, version 1, key length 128 bit
2024-11-24  9:26:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
2024-11-24  9:26:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of transaction pools: 1
2024-11-24  9:26:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
2024-11-24  9:26:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2024-11-24  9:26:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16.000GiB, chunk size = 256.000MiB
2024-11-24  9:26:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2024-11-24  9:26:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffered log writes (block size=512 bytes)
2024-11-24  9:26:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: End of log at LSN=50560061105678
2024-11-24  9:26:27 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The change buffer is corrupted
2024-11-24  9:26:27 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Data structure corruption
2024-11-24  9:26:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2024-11-24  9:26:27 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2024-11-24  9:26:27 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2024-11-24  9:26:27 0 [Note] Plugin 'wsrep-provider' is disabled.
2024-11-24  9:26:27 0 [Note] mariadbd: Plugin 'aws_key_management' already installed
2024-11-24  9:26:27 0 [Note] mariadbd: Plugin 'pam' already installed
2024-11-24  9:26:27 0 [Note] mariadbd: AWS KMS plugin: loaded key 2, version 1, key length 128 bit
2024-11-24  9:26:27 0 [Note] Using encryption key id 2 for temporary files
2024-11-24  9:26:27 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2024-11-24  9:26:27 0 [ERROR] Aborting

We can only start the database with
innodb_force_recovery = 6

But then when we try mariadb-dump, most tables show corrupted indexes with missing records.
Is there a bug in 11.4.3? Anyone have any other ideas we can try?

Did you run mariadb-upgrade after upgrade?

Yes I did @Kondybas
That also completed without any errors.
